# Change TintColor Tab Bar Item selected in iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, tintcolor

i have a problem, because since i did the last update of the SDK, my tint color for my tab bar don't run.... It stays blue tint, and not green.

I tried to do that in my viewdidload :

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

But it's not running... Someone to help me please ?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is a bit late - the view has already been loaded. Try moving that line to `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:` in your app delegate.

Comment: Seeing this in my app that just got approved today. The tint color is set globally on the storyboard's inspector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Appearance proxy API should be called **before** a view is loaded. Once `viewDidLoad` is called, it is already too late.

Move your appearance calls to the AppDelegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:`.

Comment: And it's just a bug with the SDK 7.1 which doesn't change the tint color when i set that on the storyboard ?

Comment: @Myste Not sure about that. It should work, but maybe it's a bug.

Comment: any luck? mine was when app launch no display of the tabbar items except for the selected tab and when tap all goes back to normal

Comment: Arnlee I have the same bug. no idea